# MYSQL return number of rows from a function

Tags: mysql

So, I have a table with game scores, call it RESULTS_TABLE, and let's for simplicity assume that it contains the following columns:

```
year - tournament - GameID -  player1 - player2 - winner
```

The same players can play multiple games during one tournament, in which case you would have multiple lines with the same player1/player2, but different GameIDs.

What I want to write is a function that returns the *number of opponents* one player has had in a given tournament.

I use MYSQL Workbench. In the command window I have run the following commands:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS year from RESULTS_TABLE where player1 = 'NAME' and comp = 'COMP' and year = 2015 group by player2;
select FOUND_ROWS()
```

This returns the number of opponents the player had when listed as player1 in the table. If I do another select where I swap player1 and player2 I will get the number of opponents the player had when listed as player2. Adding these will give the desired result.

My attempt for a function to achieve this, having _comp, _year and _nick as input parameters:

```
BEGIN
declare NumOfOppos int;
declare oppos1 int;
declare oppos2 int;

select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS year from RESULTS_TABLE where player1 = _nick and comp = _comp and year = _year group by player2;

select FOUND_ROWS() into oppos1;

select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS year from RESULTS_TABLE where player2 = _nick and comp = _comp and year = _year group by player1;

select FOUND_ROWS() into oppos2;

select (oppos1+oppos2) into NumOfOppos;

return NumOfOppos;
END
```

This however gives the following error when trying to create the function:

`ERROR 1415: Not allowed to return a result set from a function`

Which I don't get... Exactly where am I returning a set, I just want to return a value and I believed that what I did...

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: When you make a question regarding sql query, Always help if you provide a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) that way we can try what are you doing. Also you probably will get a better understanding by simplify the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing it all in one query?

```
select count(*)
from RESULTS_TABLE
where comp = 'COMP' and year = 2015 and
      'NAME' in (player1, player2);
```

Or if a game can be listed more than once:

```
select count(distinct gameid)
from RESULTS_TABLE
where comp = 'COMP' and year = 2015 and
      'NAME' in (player1, player2);
```

Only use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` when you need the results from the query *and* the number of rows being returned.  The normal use is pagination in applications.

Otherwise, you are returning all the data from the table, rather than just the count, which is easily calculated in SQL.

EDIT:

For the total number of opponents, the calculation is pretty similar:

```
select count(distinct (case when player1 = 'NAME' then player2
                            else player1 end)) as NumOpponents
from RESULTS_TABLE
where comp = 'COMP' and year = 2015 and
      'NAME' in (player1, player2);
```

You can even get the number of games *and* opponents in the same query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This returns the total number of GAMES, but I want the total number of OPPONENTS. And I don't really see how I can use a distinct to get it all in one query when the opponent can be in either player1 column or player2 column.

Comment: @NiklasAndersson . . .  This is much simpler as one query than as multiple queries.